# Win Task Scheduler generates multiple folders instead a zip file

Tags: windows, date, batch-file, directory, scheduled-tasks

I want to zip a project folder each month, programmed in a task scheduler executing a .bat file with the following script:

```
@echo off
set backuptime=%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "D:\backups\projects\%1\%backuptime%.backup.zip" "D:\xampp\htdocs\%1" 
echo Done!
```

%1 is the name of the project as parameter.

When I execute the bat as a Windows command (cmd), works fine generating a file: 17052022.backup.zip, but when is executed via Win task scheduler, the result is this:

[image]

Why the day and the month are a new folders?

**Solution**

Thanks for the suggestion. I have generated the zip with the date name from the O.S. configuration and not from my own user:

```
@echo off
for /f %%# in ('wmic os get localdatetime^|findstr .') do if "%%#" neq "" set date=%%#
set date=%date:~,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~6,2%
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "D:\backups\projects\%1\%date%.zip" "D:\xampp\htdocs\%1" 
echo Done!
```

Comment: `%date%` format is user-dependent. Try `echo %date%&pause` at the start of the file and observe the difference between a scheduled task running under that user and your date format. Try using a different method to determine the date in a user-independent method - many have been published on SO - use the search facility. Whatever the date format is for the scheduled task, it appears to be inserting `/`s to create the subdirectories.  Suggest you use `yyyymmdd` format for dates in filenames - sorts logically. Your posted code should insert `-` into the date-string, not `17052022` as you describe

Comment: Looking at everything you've posted, the only conclusion I can make is that you have not used the code you posted, and have instead used, ```set backuptime=%date:~4,2%/%date:~7,2%/%date:~10,4%```, ```set backuptime=%date:~4,2%\%date:~7,2%\%date:~10,4%```, or ```set backuptime=%date%```. What is certain is that your code, despite you stating otherwise, will not ever generate a file named `17052022.backup.zip`. Please be aware that, if you are running this as a Scheduled Task, the date settings defined for the user under whom the task is started will be used, not necessarily your own.